# RDF4J List of Valid Triple Indexes

Tags: rdf4j

is there a list of valid triple indexes to initialize a nativestore?

I searched in the github repo rdf4j-storage but couldn't find an enumeration or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triple stores use indexes based on *subject*, *object*, *predicate* and *context*. The index structure is given by the order of the first letter of each of these words, so, for example `spoc`, `posc` (these are the most common).
Any 4-letter permutation of these is accepted by RDF4J native store.

See for example https://github.com/eclipse/rdf4j-storage/blob/master/nativerdf/src/main/java/org/eclipse/rdf4j/sail/nativerdf/TripleStore.java, method `parseIndexSpecList`.

Comment: There is some documentation on this as well, although admittedly it's in an odd place: http://docs.rdf4j.org/server-workbench-console/#_native_store_indexes